# return to main in Python

Tags: python, return, program-entry-point

I'm new with Python command. In my program command, i need the program return to main when the the magnetic door sensor is opened. this mean when the door sensor is opened, the program will loop to the first command line. can someone help me with this? below are the command line for my program.

```
#function for door closing
def door_open():
    print("Door Open")

# function for the door closing
def door_close():
    print("Door Close")

def main():

 while True:
    if GPIO.input(door_sensor): # if door is opened
        if (sensorTrigger):
           door_open() # fire GA code
           sensorTrigger = False # make sure it doesn't fire again
        if not io.input(door_sensor): # if door is closed
            if not (sensorTrigger):
                door_close() # fire GA code
                sensorTrigger = True # make sure it doesn't fire again

door_close_thread = threading.Thread(target=door_close)
door_close_thread.daemon =  True
door_close_thread.start()

Current_State  = 0
Previous_State = 0

try:
  print "Waiting for PIR to settle..."

  # Loop until PIR output is 0
  while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)==1:
    Current_State  = 0

  print "  Ready"

  while True :

    # Read PIR state
    Current_State = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)

    if Current_State==1 and Previous_State==0:
      # PIR is triggered
      print "  Motion detected!"
      # Record previous state
      Previous_State=1
    if not Current_State==0 and Previous_State==1:
      # PIR has returned to ready state
      print "  Ready"
      Previous_State=0

# Wait for 10 milliseconds
time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit"
  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: First step would be to make a `main`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html

Comment: i have done the main. but i'm helpless in working on the return to main command whenever after the program is run till the end, when i make the door opened again i need the program to return to main. and whenever i def the main, the first while loop does't run. can u help with this?

Comment: You don't call main though. You just define a function named main.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the main function recursively.